# which chromedriver version supports electron app?

Tags: java, selenium, electron, selenium-chromedriver

I try to run electron app using the following code:

```
@Test
public void testElectron() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath);
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.setBinary(this.electronPath);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 87.0.4280.88 (89e2380a3e36c3464b5dd1302349b1382549290d-refs/branch-heads/4280@{#1761}) on port 37592
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This 
version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 87
Current browser version is 80.0.3987.165 with binary path src\main\resources\electron\electronApp.exe
```

Is there a specific chromedriver the is suitable for electron app (for selenium java)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
Current browser version is 80.0.3987.165 with binary path src\main\resources\electron\electronApp.exe
```

...implies that the *Chrome* browser version is **80.0**.

---

### Solution

So as a solution you have to download the matching [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747)
from [ChromeDriver v80.0.3987.106](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=80.0.3987.106/) repository.

Comment: using this chromedriver version solved it, but why do I have to use such an old version of chromedriver? and what do you mean chrome browser version is 80? because this is electron app. Thank you

Comment: @Roy Apologies, I hardly ever looked into _electron app_. However the error message was clear and loud that **Chrome v80.0** was in the play so you have to download and use the matching version of **ChromeDriver v80.0**.

Comment: @Roy - What version of Electron are you using? Electron is built on the Chromium rendering engine. If you upgrade Electron to 11.0 5 (or higher), does that help? See the [11.0.5 release notes](https://www.electronjs.org/releases/stable#11.0.5), where it mentions _Updated Chromium to 87.0.4280.88._

Comment: And then it will be possible to work with chromedriver 87.0.4280.88?

Comment: @Roy - that is the idea, yes. I present this as a comment, not as an answer, because I do not have any way to test it for myself. So, if you are comfortable upgrading Electron, then I would recommend doing so. But again, let me ask: **_What version of Electron are you using?_** Because if it's already up-to-date, then this approach is not going to help. (But it would be better to upgrade Electron than to downgrade the chromedriver, right?)